# python NLTK script for removing duplicate sentences

Tags: python, nltk

The purpose of my script is to go to a directory, walk through the files in the directory, remove duplicate sentences from each file and save the results for each file to a new named file.

This is the file that I used to test the script:

> This is a sentence with the word capital in it. This is a sentence
>   with the    word environment in it. This is a sentence with the word
>   environment in it.    This is a sentence with the word environment in
>   it. This is a sentence with    the word environment in it.
>
> This is a sentence with the word truck in it. This is a sentence
>   with the word    environment in it. This is a sentence with the word
>   environment in it. This is    a sentence with the word environment in
>   it. This is a sentence with the word    environment in it.

and this is the output file:

> This is a sentence with the word capital in it.This is a sentence
>   with the    word environment in it.This is a sentence with the word
>   truck in it.This is a    sentence with the word environment in it.

The problem appears to be with the tokenized form of the input file.  Printing the tokenized file to the screen shows the following:

```
  [‘This is a sentence with the word capital in it.’,’This is a sentence with 
  the word environment in it.’,’This is a sentence with the word environment in 
  it.’,’This is a sentence with the word environment in it.’This is a sentence 
  with the word truck in it.’,’ This is a sentence with the word environment in 
  it.’,’This is a sentence with the word environment in it.’,’This is a sentence 
  with the word environment in it.’,’This is a sentence with the word 
  environment in it.\n’]
```

It appears that sent_tokenizer added a \n new line symbol  at the end of the last line of input.  The sentence that has \n at the end is not recognized as a duplicate and is not removed.

Any insights into what is happening and what I can do to correct the problem is appreciated.

```
import os, os.path,re, pprint,sys, nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in fileList:   
        with open (filename,'r') as fin:            
            FileinA=(fin.read())                
            FileinB=nltk.sent_tokenize(FileinA)             
            print ('2 Tokenized File')              
            print (FileinB)             
            print (' ')             
            #create basename by deleting the file name suffix       
            basename=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]              
            print (' 3 Basename')           
            print (' ')             
            print (basename)                
            print(' ')              
            sent_seen = set() # holds lines already seen            
            with open (basename+'XXX'+'.txt', 'a') as filetowrite:      
                for sent in FileinB:                    
                    if sent not in sent_seen:               
                        filetowrite.write(sent)         
                        print (' ')                 
                        sent_seen.add(sent)         
                        print (sent_seen)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the beginning and ending whitespaces of a sentence do not matter, you can add a line `sent = sent.strip()` to get rid of `\n` and any other potential trailing whitespaces.

```
        with open (basename+'XXX'+'.txt', 'a') as filetowrite:      
            for sent in FileinB:  
                sent = sent.strip()    # added                 
                if sent not in sent_seen:               
                    filetowrite.write(sent)         
                    print (' ')                 
                    sent_seen.add(sent)         
                    print (sent_seen)
```

Comment: Thanks, that took care of the \n.  Any idea how the \n would appear in the output?  Looks to me like sent_tokenize should have elimated it?

Comment: @RJS I am not familiar with the package enough to answer the question. Sorry.